# Why subset doesn't work with string column names when removing columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

Consider the following dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:5, y=6:10, z=11:15, a=16:20)
```

I can select a column using just the name:

```
df2 <- subset (df, select = x)
```

Or I can select it passing the name as a string:

```
df2 <- subset (df, select = c("x"))
```

I can delete a column by passing just the name:

```
df2 <- subset (df, select = -x)
```

But I cannot delete it passing the name as string:

```
df2 <- subset (df, select = -c("x"))
```

As it returns the error:

```
Error in -c("x") : invalid argument to unary operator
```

Why?

Comment: According to `?subset` `select - expression, indicating columns to select from a data frame` i.e. try `subset (df, select = setdiff(names(df), c("x")))`

Comment: The `select=` parameter basically is evaluated within an environment where the column names are turned into their respective indexes. So like `with(setNames(as.list(seq_along(df)), names(df)), -x)` So you can use `-` with symbols because those are turning into numbers. But you can't use `-` with strings ever. You can see how this works if you look at the source of the function by typing `subset.data.frame` without the parens at the console.